# Spinner first item default set empty value?

Tags: android

Here in this code i have added pincode numbers from 600000 to 600113 in the spinner but i want the first position to be just empty. When the user clicks only then the item should be shown. Please see my code -

```
final String[] myarray=new String[114];

    for(int i=0;i<114;i++)
    {

    myarray[i]=String.valueOf(a);
    a++;
    }
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,myarray);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    addnum_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickedListener);

  //Spinner click  

    addnum_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
            String value = myarray[position];

            //
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

add this property to your `spinner` in `xml` and try if that works

```
android:prompt=""
```

Comment: I am put in android:prompt="@string/spinner"   value folder i have add <string name="spinner">"Select First Item"</string> but again i got first value 600000.

Comment: try putting hard coded string android:prompt="Select First Item" in place of android:prompt="@string/spinner"

Comment: Or if possible set the first value of your array as array[0] = "Select First Item"

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'prompt' with value 'Select 
  First Item').
 - [I18N] Hardcoded string "Select First Item", should use @string 
  resource

Comment: I try it  for(int i=0;i<114;i++)
  {
   if(i == 0)
   {
     myarray[i] = "Select First Item";
   }
   
  myarray[i]=String.valueOf(a);
  a++;
  }

Comment: for(int i=0;i<114;i++) { if(i == 0) { myarray[i] = "Select First Item"; }else{ myarray[i]=String.valueOf(a); a++;} }
try this

Comment: Please see my previous comments i am already put in same code but i didn't get any result

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way but what about just adding the empty string before the for loop as the first item and then you just have to handle the user clicking on the empty item in your Listener. Something like

```
final String[] myarray=new String[115];
    myarray[0] = ""
    for(int i=1;i<115;i++)
    {

    myarray[i]=String.valueOf(a);
    a++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I'm adding a solution. I found this out on accident, as I DIDN'T want a blank default value, but there was one.

If using an ArrayAdapter, I found that attaching the adapter to an empty ArrayList, and THEN filling it left a blank initial value.

Filling the ArrayList first, then attaching the ArrayAdapter removed the blank default value.

Obviously, if not using an ArrayAdapter, using the prompt, or setting the first Spinner item as `<item></item>` with nothing in between in the XML should work.